# Under what circumstances are views wrapping divs required?

Tags: 8, views

When I embed a view, I'm seeing the following wrapping divs (Note: I'm using just the core views module templates):

```
<div class="views-element-container">
  <div class="js-view-dom-id-ETC">
    // Content I care about here
  </div>
</div>
```

I've seen the same kind of component on a number of projects: A paragraph (or block, or whatever) where a user can manually choose a number of blog posts, via entity_reference, or they can enter a tag and have the component populate with the most recent blog posts of that tag. Typically, I embed a view with contextual filter for the *most recent by tag* option, and just display the field if they're manually chosen.

The annoying issue I run in to is that the markup is different, largely because of these two divs. For example:

```
// Manually Selected:
<div class="my-element">
  <article />
  <article />
  <article />
</div>

// Tag selected:
<div class="my-element">
  <div class="views-element-container">
    <div class="js-view-dom-id-ETC">
      <article />
      <article />
      <article />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I see that the `js-view-dom-id-ETC` div is added in `views-view.html.twig` and can be easily removed - my assumption here is that if my view is not interactive (no paging, no filters, it'd never be refreshed in any way - it's really just used as a query builder) then it's totally fine to remove this div.

The `views-element-container` div is a little more complicated to get rid of, but again, I'm assuming it's fine to do so if my view is not interactive.

Doing a string search of the views module for `views-element-container`, I can see that it's only referenced in tests.

From a functional standpoint, are my assumptions correct here? Are these divs only necessary with interactive views that use AJAX?

**Edit:**
Per my testing, it seems removing these two divs does no harm for my embedded views with no interaction.

Comment: BigPipe might be a thing too, since it replaces blocks using Ajax